# Acumatica: How do I get the current Short Date and Long Time Format in a Generic Inquiries?

Tags: acumatica

We are using Acumatica WEB API to run GI; but sometimes the the DateTime parameters does not works becouse the side that run the GI does NOT match de localization settings with the user's login localization.

Before run the GI, I need to read the User preference's Localization or the Site Default Localization (where the user haz no access to his own localization settings)

So far I have found the way to get the current user logged in and the next tables:

```
_UserSide_
Users->UserPreferences
UserPreferences->UserLocaleFormat
UserLocaleFormat->LocaleFormat

_SiteDefault_
Locale->LocaleFormat
```

Before I go further... is any simple way to get the current localization for the loged user in a GI?

Cos' I getting some weirds id's for the FormatID fields.

Answer (score 1):

Found the solution to get the Locale Date Time pattern for the current login user:

When the User has Access to his own profile, the localitation comes from:
Users->UserPreferences->UserLocaleFormat->LocalFormat

When the user has NOT access to his own profile or are blank:
Locale->LocaleFormat    (where Locale.IsActive=true and Locale.IsDefault=true)

Here is the GI for Acumatica v. 6.0 (caution this will repalace the GI whit ID GI00000001)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" standalone="yes"?>
<data-set>
  <relations format-version="3" relations-version="20160530" main-table="GIDesign">
    <link from="GIFilter (DesignID)" to="GIDesign (DesignID)" />
    <link from="GIGroupBy (DesignID)" to="GIDesign (DesignID)" />
    <link from="GIMassAction (DesignID)" to="GIDesign (DesignID)" />
    <link from="GIMassUpdateField (DesignID)" to="GIDesign (DesignID)" />
    <link from="GINavigationScreen (DesignID)" to="GIDesign (DesignID)" />
    <link from="GINavigationParameter (DesignID, ScreenID)" to="GINavigationScreen (DesignID, ScreenID)" />
    <link from="GIOn (DesignID, RelationNbr)" to="GIRelation (DesignID, LineNbr)" />
    <link from="GIRecordDefault (DesignID)" to="GIDesign (DesignID)" />
    <link from="GIRelation (DesignID, ParentTable)" to="GITable (DesignID, Alias)" />
    <link from="GIRelation (DesignID, ChildTable)" to="GITable (DesignID, Alias)" />
    <link from="GIResult (DesignID)" to="GIDesign (DesignID)" />
    <link from="GIResult (ObjectName, DesignID)" to="GITable (Alias, DesignID)" />
    <link from="GISort (DesignID)" to="GIDesign (DesignID)" />
    <link from="GITable (DesignID)" to="GIDesign (DesignID)" />
    <link from="GIWhere (DesignID)" to="GIDesign (DesignID)" />
    <link from="SiteMap (Url)" to="GIDesign (DesignID)" type="WeakByUrl" linkname="toDesignById" baseurl="~/GenericInquiry/GenericInquiry.aspx" paramnames="id" />
    <link from="SiteMap (Url)" to="GIDesign (Name)" type="WeakByUrl" linkname="toDesignByName" baseurl="~/GenericInquiry/GenericInquiry.aspx" />
    <link from="ListEntryPoint (ListScreenID)" to="SiteMap (ScreenID)" />
    <link from="SiteMap (ScreenID)" to="GIDesign (PrimaryScreenIDNew)" linkname="to1Screen" />
    <link from="SiteMap (NodeID)" to="SiteMap (ParentID)" type="WeakToParent" recursive-nesting="yes" include-parents="False" />
    <link from="GIDesign (NoteID)" to="Note (NoteID)" type="Note" />
    <link from="GIFilter (NoteID)" to="Note (NoteID)" type="Note" />
    <link from="GIFilter (NoteID)" to="GIFilterKvExt (RecordID)" type="RowKvExt" />
    <link from="GIGroupBy (NoteID)" to="Note (NoteID)" type="Note" />
    <link from="GIOn (NoteID)" to="Note (NoteID)" type="Note" />
    <link from="GIRelation (NoteID)" to="Note (NoteID)" type="Note" />
    <link from="GIResult (NoteID)" to="Note (NoteID)" type="Note" />
    <link from="GIResult (NoteID)" to="GIResultKvExt (RecordID)" type="RowKvExt" />
    <link from="GISort (NoteID)" to="Note (NoteID)" type="Note" />
    <link from="GITable (NoteID)" to="Note (NoteID)" type="Note" />
    <link from="GIWhere (NoteID)" to="Note (NoteID)" type="Note" />
  </relations>
  <layout>
    <table name="GIDesign">
      <table name="GIFilter" uplink="(DesignID) = (DesignID)">
        <table name="Note" uplink="(NoteID) = (NoteID)" />
        <table name="GIFilterKvExt" uplink="(NoteID) = (RecordID)" />
      </table>
      <table name="GIGroupBy" uplink="(DesignID) = (DesignID)">
        <table name="Note" uplink="(NoteID) = (NoteID)" />
      </table>
      <table name="GIMassAction" uplink="(DesignID) = (DesignID)" />
      <table name="GIMassUpdateField" uplink="(DesignID) = (DesignID)" />
      <table name="GINavigationScreen" uplink="(DesignID) = (DesignID)">
        <table name="GINavigationParameter" uplink="(DesignID, ScreenID) = (DesignID, ScreenID)" />
      </table>
      <table name="GIRecordDefault" uplink="(DesignID) = (DesignID)" />
      <table name="GISort" uplink="(DesignID) = (DesignID)">
        <table name="Note" uplink="(NoteID) = (NoteID)" />
      </table>
      <table name="GITable" uplink="(DesignID) = (DesignID)">
        <table name="GIRelation" uplink="(DesignID, Alias) = (DesignID, ParentTable)">
          <table name="GIOn" uplink="(DesignID, LineNbr) = (DesignID, RelationNbr)">
            <table name="Note" uplink="(NoteID) = (NoteID)" />
          </table>
          <table name="Note" uplink="(NoteID) = (NoteID)" />
        </table>
        <table name="GIResult" uplink="(Alias, DesignID) = (ObjectName, DesignID)">
          <table name="Note" uplink="(NoteID) = (NoteID)" />
          <table name="GIResultKvExt" uplink="(NoteID) = (RecordID)" />
        </table>
        <table name="Note" uplink="(NoteID) = (NoteID)" />
      </table>
      <table name="GIWhere" uplink="(DesignID) = (DesignID)">
        <table name="Note" uplink="(NoteID) = (NoteID)" />
      </table>
      <table name="SiteMap" uplink="(DesignID) = (Url)" recursion="(NodeID) = (ParentID)" linkname="toDesignById">
        <table name="ListEntryPoint" uplink="(ScreenID) = (ListScreenID)" />
      </table>
      <table name="SiteMap" uplink="(Name) = (Url)" recursion="(NodeID) = (ParentID)" linkname="toDesignByName">
        <table name="ListEntryPoint" uplink="(ScreenID) = (ListScreenID)" />
      </table>
      <table name="SiteMap" uplink="(PrimaryScreenIDNew) = (ScreenID)" recursion="(NodeID) = (ParentID)" linkname="to1Screen">
        <table name="ListEntryPoint" uplink="(ScreenID) = (ListScreenID)" />
      </table>
      <table name="Note" uplink="(NoteID) = (NoteID)" />
    </table>
  </layout>
  <data>
    <GIDesign>
      <row DesignID="5f1395b0-a36e-479a-8911-2ad48d885bde" Name="ITOS_GI_Heartbeat" SelectTop="1" FilterColCount="3" PagerStyle="0" PageSize="0" NewRecordCreationEnabled="0" MassDeleteEnabled="0" AutoConfirmDelete="0" MassRecordsUpdateEnabled="0" MassActionsOnRecordsEnabled="0" ExposeViaOData="0">
        <GIFilter LineNbr="1" IsActive="0" Name="Username" FieldName="Users.username" DataType="string" DisplayName="Username" IsExpression="0" DefaultValue="Admin" ColSpan="1" Required="0">
          <GIFilterKvExt FieldName="DisplayNameEN" ValueText="Username" />
        </GIFilter>
        <GISort LineNbr="6" IsActive="1" DataFieldName="LocaleFormat.formatID" SortOrder="D" />
        <GITable Alias="Locale" Name="PX.SM.Locale">
          <GIResult LineNbr="7" IsActive="0" Field="localeName" Caption="L LoacaleName" IsVisible="1" DefaultNav="1">
            <GIResultKvExt FieldName="CaptionEN" ValueText="L LoacaleName" />
          </GIResult>
          <GIResult LineNbr="14" IsActive="0" Field="formatID" Caption="L FormatID" IsVisible="1" DefaultNav="1">
            <GIResultKvExt FieldName="CaptionEN" ValueText="L FormatID" />
          </GIResult>
        </GITable>
        <GITable Alias="LocaleFormat" Name="PX.SM.LocaleFormat">
          <GIResult LineNbr="3" IsActive="1" Field="dateShortPattern" Caption="ULFLocaleNaqme" IsVisible="1" DefaultNav="1">
            <GIResultKvExt FieldName="CaptionEN" ValueText="DateShortPattern" />
            <GIResultKvExt FieldName="CaptionES" ValueText="ULFLocaleNaqme" />
          </GIResult>
          <GIResult LineNbr="4" IsActive="1" Field="timeLongPattern" Caption="DateShort" IsVisible="1" DefaultNav="1">
            <GIResultKvExt FieldName="CaptionEN" ValueText="TimeLongPattern" />
            <GIResultKvExt FieldName="CaptionES" ValueText="DateShort" />
          </GIResult>
          <GIResult LineNbr="5" IsActive="1" Field="templateLocale" Caption="TimeLong" IsVisible="1" DefaultNav="1">
            <GIResultKvExt FieldName="CaptionEN" ValueText="LocaleName" />
            <GIResultKvExt FieldName="CaptionES" ValueText="TimeLong" />
          </GIResult>
          <GIResult LineNbr="11" IsActive="0" Field="templateLocale" Caption="LF TemplateLocale" IsVisible="1" DefaultNav="1">
            <GIResultKvExt FieldName="CaptionEN" ValueText="LF TemplateLocale" />
          </GIResult>
          <GIResult LineNbr="13" IsActive="0" Field="formatID" Caption="LF FormatID" IsVisible="1" DefaultNav="1">
            <GIResultKvExt FieldName="CaptionEN" ValueText="LF FormatID" />
          </GIResult>
        </GITable>
        <GITable Alias="LoginTrace" Name="PX.SM.LoginTrace">
          <GIRelation LineNbr="3" ChildTable="Users" IsActive="1" JoinType="I">
            <GIOn LineNbr="12" ParentField="username" Condition="E " ChildField="username" Operation="A" />
          </GIRelation>
          <GIResult LineNbr="1" IsActive="1" Field="=Concat( CStr(Year(Now())), PadRight(CStr(Month(Now())),2,'0'), PadRight(CStr(Day(Now())),2,'0'), PadRight(CStr(Hour(Now())),2,'0'),PadRight(CStr(Minute(Now())),2,'0'), PadRight(CStr(Second(Now())),2,'0') )" Caption="Today" IsVisible="1" DefaultNav="1">
            <GIResultKvExt FieldName="CaptionEN" ValueText="NowWindev" />
            <GIResultKvExt FieldName="CaptionES" ValueText="Today" />
          </GIResult>
          <GIResult LineNbr="2" IsActive="1" Field="=Now()" Caption="Now" IsVisible="1" DefaultNav="1">
            <GIResultKvExt FieldName="CaptionEN" ValueText="NowAcumatica" />
            <GIResultKvExt FieldName="CaptionES" ValueText="Now" />
          </GIResult>
        </GITable>
        <GITable Alias="UserLocaleFormat" Name="PX.SM.UserLocaleFormat">
          <GIRelation LineNbr="7" ChildTable="LocaleFormat" IsActive="1" JoinType="L">
            <GIOn LineNbr="22" ParentField="UserLocaleFormat.formatID" Condition="E " ChildField="formatID" Operation="O" />
            <GIOn LineNbr="23" ParentField="Locale.formatID" Condition="E " ChildField="formatID" Operation="O" />
          </GIRelation>
          <GIResult LineNbr="6" IsActive="0" Field="localeName" Caption="User" IsVisible="1" DefaultNav="1">
            <GIResultKvExt FieldName="CaptionEN" ValueText="ULF LocaleName" />
            <GIResultKvExt FieldName="CaptionES" ValueText="User" />
          </GIResult>
          <GIResult LineNbr="9" IsActive="0" Field="userID" Caption="ULF UserID" IsVisible="1" DefaultNav="1">
            <GIResultKvExt FieldName="CaptionEN" ValueText="ULF UserID" />
          </GIResult>
          <GIResult LineNbr="12" IsActive="0" Field="formatID" Caption="ULF FormatID" IsVisible="1" DefaultNav="1">
            <GIResultKvExt FieldName="CaptionEN" ValueText="ULF FormatID" />
          </GIResult>
        </GITable>
        <GITable Alias="UserPreferences" Name="PX.SM.UserPreferences">
          <GIRelation LineNbr="6" ChildTable="UserLocaleFormat" IsActive="1" JoinType="F">
            <GIOn LineNbr="24" ParentField="userID" Condition="E " ChildField="userID" Operation="A" />
          </GIRelation>
          <GIResult LineNbr="8" IsActive="0" Field="userID" Caption="UserPreferences UserID" IsVisible="1" DefaultNav="1">
            <GIResultKvExt FieldName="CaptionEN" ValueText="UserPreferences UserID" />
          </GIResult>
        </GITable>
        <GITable Alias="Users" Name="PX.SM.Users">
          <GIRelation LineNbr="4" ChildTable="Locale" IsActive="1" JoinType="L">
            <GIOn LineNbr="26" ParentField="isOnLine" Condition="E " ChildField="isDefault" Operation="A" />
            <GIOn LineNbr="27" ParentField="isOnLine" Condition="E " ChildField="isActive" Operation="A" />
          </GIRelation>
          <GIRelation LineNbr="5" ChildTable="UserPreferences" IsActive="1" JoinType="I">
            <GIOn LineNbr="25" ParentField="pKID" Condition="E " ChildField="userID" Operation="A" />
          </GIRelation>
          <GIResult LineNbr="10" IsActive="0" Field="username" Caption="Users Username" IsVisible="1" DefaultNav="1">
            <GIResultKvExt FieldName="CaptionEN" ValueText="Users Username" />
          </GIResult>
        </GITable>
        <GIWhere LineNbr="1" IsActive="0" DataFieldName="Users.username" Condition="E " IsExpression="0" Value1="[Username]" Operation="A" />
        <GIWhere LineNbr="2" IsActive="1" DataFieldName="Users.isOnLine" Condition="E " IsExpression="1" Value1="True" Value2="False" Operation="A" />
        <GIWhere LineNbr="3" IsActive="1" DataFieldName="LoginTrace.screenID" Condition="E " IsExpression="1" Value1="GI000001" Operation="A" />
        <GIWhere LineNbr="5" IsActive="1" OpenBrackets="((       " DataFieldName="UserLocaleFormat.userID" Condition="NU" IsExpression="0" CloseBrackets=")        " Operation="O" />
        <GIWhere LineNbr="6" IsActive="1" OpenBrackets="(        " DataFieldName="UserLocaleFormat.userID" Condition="NN" IsExpression="0" Operation="A" />
        <GIWhere LineNbr="7" IsActive="1" DataFieldName="UserLocaleFormat.formatID" Condition="NN" IsExpression="0" Operation="A" />
        <GIWhere LineNbr="8" IsActive="1" DataFieldName="LocaleFormat.formatID" Condition="E " IsExpression="0" Value1="UserLocaleFormat.FormatID" CloseBrackets="))       " Operation="A" />
        <SiteMap linkname="toDesignById">
          <row Position="59" Title="ITOS GI Heartbeat" Url="~/GenericInquiry/GenericInquiry.aspx?id=5f1395b0-a36e-479a-8911-2ad48d885bde" Expanded="0" IsFolder="0" ScreenID="GI000001" NodeID="00bdd816-dcb2-44b5-b0e0-83f608e35d9f" ParentID="702a9fc5-bf44-4421-b339-4c2da7a32582">
            <SiteMap Position="127" Title="Consultas Generales" Expanded="0" IsFolder="0" NodeID="702a9fc5-bf44-4421-b339-4c2da7a32582">
              <SiteMap Position="589" Title="Work Area" Description="main@DataEntryF" Expanded="1" IsFolder="0" NodeID="de0d5687-3c67-4ec7-94e9-2c3e5225f817">
                <SiteMap Position="516" Title="Sales Orders" Url="~/Frames/Default.aspx" Expanded="0" IsFolder="0" ScreenID="SO000000" NodeID="ff2d3fd4-ab02-43c9-ad02-aad212542770">
                  <SiteMap Position="30" Title="Distribution" Url="~/Frames/Default.aspx" Expanded="0" IsFolder="0" ScreenID="DS000000" NodeID="91d578ba-75b6-4fa9-a532-9457a6383a62">
                    <SiteMap Position="0" Title="Sitemap Root" Url="~/Frames/Default.aspx" Expanded="0" IsFolder="0" ScreenID="00000000" NodeID="00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000" />
                  </SiteMap>
                </SiteMap>
              </SiteMap>
            </SiteMap>
          </row>
        </SiteMap>
        <Note NoteText="Now(): Returns the current date and time according to the system date and time on the local computer.&#xA;&#xA;NowUTC(): Returns the current date and time according to the user’s time zone.&#xA;The system gets the user’s time zone from the following sources, which are ordered by the priority from the highest to the lowest:&#xA;&#xA;1. User’s preferences specified on the User Profile (SM.20.30.10) form.&#xA;2. The employee calendar specified on the Work Calendar (CS.20.90.00) form and selected for the user's employee on the Employees (EP.20.30.00) form.&#xA;3. Site preferences specified on the on the Site Preferences (SM.20.05.05) form." GraphType="PX.Data.Maintenance.GI.GenericInquiryDesigner" EntityType="PX.Data.Maintenance.GI.GIDesign" />
      </row>
    </GIDesign>
  </data>
</data-set>
```